# Image rotate with css is hiding the image in horizontal wise even though I Enable scrolling system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to rotate the very large size image through css rotate concept dynamically and when I rotate the rectangular image horizontally the image is getting hidden towards left eventhough i use CSS overflow Auto. Could you please help me on this.

```
<style>
    .rotated {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        overflow:auto;  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
    }
    .slider{
        margin-left:35%;
        margin-top:10%;
    }
    .sliderLarge{
        position:relative;
        top:0%;
        left:20%;
        display:none;
        overflow:auto !important;       
    }
    button{
        background-color:green;
        padding:12px;
        border-radius:4px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        color:#fff;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-top:20px;        
    }
    .sliderImage{
        //margin:50px 2px;
    }
    button.Enlarge{
        margin-left:15%;
    }
    button.closeIcon{
        margin-left:32%;
    }
    button.rotate{
        margin-left:1%;
        background-color:orange;
        color:#000;             
    }
    button:hover{
        background-color:#ccc;
        color:#000;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="Picture1.png" width="40%" height="auto">
        <div></div>
        <button class="Enlarge">Enlarge</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderLarge" style="width:800px;height:800px;">
        <img src="Picture1.png" class="sliderImage" >
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="closeIcon">Close</button>
    <button class="rotate">Rotate</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you set up a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**, also including your JS code?